# Error HH801: Plugin @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox requires the following dependencies to be installed:

Tags: hardhat, yarn-lock.json

```
yarn hardhat
yarn run v1.22.19
$ D:\Codeing\Blockchain\hardhat\node_modules\.bin\hardhat
Error HH801: Plugin @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox requires the following dependencies to be installed: @ethersproject/providers, @nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers, @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers, @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers, @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan, @types/chai, @types/mocha, @typechain/ethers-v5, @typechain/hardhat, chai, ethers, hardhat-gas-reporter, solidity-coverage, ts-node, typechain, typescript.
Please run: npm install --save-dev "@ethersproject/providers@^5.4.7" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers@^1.0.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@^1.0.0" "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@^2.0.0" "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan@^3.0.0" "@types/chai@^4.2.0" "@types/mocha@>=9.1.0" "@typechain/ethers-v5@^10.1.0" "@typechain/hardhat@^6.1.2" "chai@^4.2.0" "ethers@^5.4.7" "hardhat-gas-reporter@^1.0.8" "solidity-coverage@^0.8.1" "ts-node@>=8.0.0" "typechain@^8.1.0" "typescript@>=4.5.0"
```

I am facing this issues when trying to yarn hardhat

Comment: Just run command in console to install all these dependencies.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this issue then you can install following dependancies, it worked fine for me

```
npm install --save-dev "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers@^1.0.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@^1.0.0" "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@^2.0.0" "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan@^3.0.0" "@types/chai@^4.2.0" "@types/mocha@^9.1.0" "@typechain/ethers-v5@^10.1.0" "@typechain/hardhat@^6.1.2" "chai@^4.2.0" "hardhat-gas-reporter@^1.0.8" "solidity-coverage@^0.7.21" "ts-node@>=8.0.0" "typechain@^8.1.0" "typescript@>=4.5.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the instruction below the Error (You can copy and then paste it)

```
npm install --save-dev ...
```

[image]